# Overriding Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in html

```
<div class="pru">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="bo">
    <li class="bos"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
body div ul li.bos {
-webkit-transition: background-color 5s !important;
}

.pru {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 250px auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

body div ul li.bos:hover {
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

I want to change the color of the "li" component from blue to green when I hover it, but bootstrap overrides my code, and change the color to grey. How can I override Bootstrap code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bootstrap applies the `background-color` to the `a` element not the `li`. You should adjust your css to effect the `a` tag like so

```
body div ul li.bos:hover a{
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: @user2814276 you're welcome, please dont forget to mark the answer to your question so that others may find it.